# AWS CloudWatch Composite Alarm Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms, aws-organizations

I have a use case where I want to share my alarms with a specific monitor account within AWS organization. What I then would want to do is to create a composite alarm of all shared alarms. Is this not possible? The "create composite alarm" is greyed out even when I have full cloudwatch permissions set for the monitor account.

"You can combine metrics from different accounts using Metric Math and organize cross account alarms into hierarchies using composite alarms in the monitoring account."

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/08/announcing-amazon-cloudwatch-cross-account-alarms/

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue at all ? I was able to view metrics, and alarms but cant create alarms at all. The aws docs are not clear on what exactly is needed as the default sharing is read-only. Wonder if need to manually modify the IAM permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html):

> In the list of alarms, select the check **boxes** next to each of the existing alarms that you want to reference in your new composite alarm. Then choose Create composite alarm.

You need **multiple** alarms to create a composite alarm.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AWS official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Create_Composite_Alarm.html):

> All of the underlying alarms in your composite alarm must be in the same account and the same Region as your composite alarm. However, if you set up a composite alarm in a CloudWatch cross-account observability monitoring account, the underlying alarms can watch metrics in different source accounts and in the monitoring account itself. For more information, see CloudWatch cross-account observability.

You cannot create a composite alarm with the across-account alarms.

So you may need to use a 'CloudWatch cross-account observability monitoring account' to do this.

Another way is that you can create the same alarms with across-account metrics in current account, and then use those alarms to create the composite alarms.